# How to Use HttpClient the Correct Way Passing Credentials to Handler in .NET 6 to Avoid Socket Exhaustion

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In my API project, I am using appsettings.json to store a service account that can be changed at any time dynamically through a configuration center that I built.

In my Web project, I'm using the below to pull a list of domains.  The service account is a user account in the domain.  Working excerpt:

```
public DomainManagementClient(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public List<ManagedDomains> GetDomainDropdownList()
{

    List<ManagedDomains> OnlineDCs = new List<ManagedDomains>();

    var user = _configuration["ServiceAccount:ServiceAccountLogonName"];
    var pwd = _configuration["ServiceAccount:ServiceAccountPassword"];

    var uri = new Uri("http://test.local/api/DomainManagement/GetAllAvailableDomains");
    var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache
    {
        { uri, "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(user, pwd) }
    };

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credentialsCache, PreAuthenticate = true };
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        OnlineDCs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ManagedDomains>>(data);
    }

    return OnlineDCs;

}
```

I understand the concept of socket exhaustion and I purposefully tested this with a macro flooding refreshes and it eventually broke as expected from too many clients.

How could I get this to work with the NTLM credentials that are passed in the handler if I instantiate it at the top of the code once, so it doesn't use multiple clients, with:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient
{

}
```

I don't want to do it in "program.cs", because I will not be able to pull the "_configuration["ServiceAccount:ServiceAccountLogonName"]" since "program.cs" is fired once at launch and won't take changes to appsettings.json dynamically.

In "program.cs":

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDomainManagementClient, DomainManagementClient>();
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing the following, however, when I change just the username in appsettings.json WHILE the app is running, it takes about a minute or two until it updates in the Web app.

"Program.cs"

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"{Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())}/API/appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IDomainManagementClient, DomainManagementClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.local/api/api/DomainManagement/GetAllAvailableDomains");
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    var user = builder.Configuration["ServiceAccount:ServiceAccountLogonName"];
    var pwd = builder.Configuration["ServiceAccount:ServiceAccountPassword"];

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
    return new SocketsHttpHandler
    {
        Credentials = credentials,
        PreAuthenticate = true
    };

});
```

"DomainManagementClient.cs"

```
public class DomainManagementClient : IDomainManagementClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public DomainManagementClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public List<ManagedDomains> GetDomainDropdownList()
    {

        List<ManagedDomains> OnlineDCs = new List<ManagedDomains>();
        var uri = new Uri("http://test.local/api/api/DomainManagement/GetAllAvailableDomains");
    
        HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync(uri).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            OnlineDCs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ManagedDomains>>(data);
        }

        return OnlineDCs;

    }
}
```

Does anything stick out like a sore thumb in my update that would cause a delay when I am dynamically, locally, changing appsettings.json value:

```
"ServiceAccount": {
  "ServiceAccountLogonName": "test\\test.admin.acc",
  "ServiceAccountPassword": "*********"
},
```

My API and Web applications are both published to a VM running IIS.  So when I say that I am changing the username in appsettings.json, I'm changing it locally on the IIS server, not restarting the IIS server, and not republishing.

When I was running httpclient in GetDomainDropdownList(), in the top of the original post, and changing appsettings.json locally, the changes were reflected immediately but it's just not reflecting immediately with the credentials being set in "program.cs".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's recommanded to use IHttpclientFactory to avoid socket exhaustion,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use) related:

> The factory pools HttpMessageHandler instances, and, if its lifetime
> hasn't expired, a handler can be reused from the pool when the factory
> creates a new HttpClient instance. This reuse avoids any socket
> exhaustion issues.

You could  configure credeta if necessary as below:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("clientname", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = ........
})
.ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder => new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = new CredentialCache
    {
         ........
    }
});
```

> I don't want to do it in "program.cs", because I will not be able to
> pull the "_configuration["ServiceAccount:ServiceAccountLogonName"]"
> since "program.cs" is fired once at launch and won't take changes to
> appsettings.json dynamically.

It's not correct,since you've registed it in DI container,every time you create a new instance,it would read the property from IConfiguration, let's try with a simple test:
I configured httpclient as below:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("client1", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetSection("BaseAddress").Value);
})
```

when I debug:

[image]